# Chain rule, time derivative and change of variables

Tags: calculus

A simple calculus question. If I apply the chain rule to a composite function:

$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x(t))\frac{dx}{dt}$$
Now, if I change variables, and define:

$$x=x_1+\lambda x_2$$

I can say:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x_1(t),x_2(t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f(x_1(t),x_2(t))\frac{dx_1}{dt}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}f(x_1(t),x_2(t))\frac{dx_2}{dt}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

but also
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\lambda ^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$$
so that, from the equation at the top
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\lambda ^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\right]f(x_1(t)+\lambda x_2(t))\left(\frac{dx_1}{dt}+\lambda\frac{dx_2}{dt}\right)$$

How does this relate to the third equation?

Comment: Why is

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\lambda ^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\;?
$$

Comment: Because $\frac{df}{dx}=\sum \frac{df}{dx_i}\cdot \frac{dx_i}{dx}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original equation you wrote, all you have is a function of one variable inside a function of one variable, so using $\partial$ isn't necessary.  Just use the chain rule from Calculus I:  $$ \frac{d}{dt} f(x(t)) = \frac{df}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$$

When you make the change of variables $x = x_1 + \lambda x_2$, what you really have is $$f(x(x_1(t), x_2(t))),$$ not $$f(x_1(t), x_2(t)).$$  So then you would have:

\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{dt}f(x(x_1(t), x_2(t))) 
    &= \frac{d}{dx} f(x(x_1(t), x_2(t))) \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{d}{dx} f(x(x_1(t), x_2(t))) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_1} \frac{dx_1}{dt} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial x_2} \frac{dx_2}{dt}\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \underbrace{f'(x(x_1(t), x_2(t)))}_{\color{red}{df/dx}} \cdot \underbrace{\left(\frac{dx_1}{dt} + \lambda \frac{dx_2}{dt}\right)}_{\color{red}{dx/dt}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. But isn't $\frac{df}{dx}=\sum \frac{df}{dx_i}\cdot \frac{dx_i}{dx}$?

Comment: No, $df/dx$ is just $df/dx$ because $f$ is just a function of $x.$  Then $x$ itself is a function of $x_1$ and $x_2,$ and those two are functions of $t.$  Saying $dx_i/dx$ doesn't work (in this context) because $x_i$ is not a function of $x,$ it's the other way around.

Comment: But I can always say $x_2=(x-x_1)\lambda$. Does that not make sense? Probably we are saying that it works for an $\tilde f(x_1,x_2):=f(x(x_1,x_2))$

Comment: $x_2 = (x-x_1)/\lambda$ is what you meant, I think.  And yes, you can say that, but it isn't necessary here and doesn't help.  In this scenario we explicitly have $f$ as a function of $x,$ explicitly have $x$ as a function of both $x_1$ and $x_2,$ and explicitly have $x_1$ and $x_2$ as functions of $t.$  If we want $df/dt$ then the chain rule tells us to follow that "chain" of functions: $f \to x \to (x_1, x_2) \to t.$  Expressing $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $x$ is sort of like going backwards.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\frac{df(x)}{dt}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}(\frac{dx}{dx_1}\frac{dx_1}{dt}+\frac{dx}{dx_2}\frac{dx_2}{dt})=\frac{df(x)}{dx}(\frac{dx_1}{dt}+\lambda^{-1}\frac{dx_2}{dt})
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}